# ASP .Net TreeView doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, treeview, azure-web-app-service

I have a page with a TreeView control.
It behaves correctly when I try to start the WebApp form Visual Studio and browse the WebApp on localhost.
When I try to load it up on the website (azurewebsites.net) the TreeView does not show images, and there is no way to expand/collapse nodes.
It doesn't find the resource file from with to download images and does not find the javascript functions needed for the TreeView to work.

Comment: Did you check the javascript, images file path after hosting it in azure?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the URLs for the javascript and images sent in the generated web pages?

Comment: Them are both fetched with a request on the file WebResource.axd that is not found

Comment: The fact that WebResource.axd is not found doesn't imply that i found the solution to the problem. That file is not a regular file in the project directory tree. It handles resource requests that should be handled by IIS, AFAIK.